# How access to app from controller/EJS? Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, controller, ejs, sails.js

I want to access to app.routes from my controller or EJS view, but app var don't exists there.
Do you know how can I access to all the routes that I defined myself in config/routes.js?

Thank you.

PS: I'm using sails.js, based on express.js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `request.app`:

```
app.get('/foo', function (request, response, next) {
  console.log(request.app.routes);
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it works like this: (Controller)
    module.exports = {
        index: function (req, res) {
        return res.view({
            layout: 'layout',
            title: 'Trip Analyzer',
            routes: req.app.routes
        });
    }
    };
  
And if I use: (View EJS)  
    <% console.log(routes) %>
I create like an infinite while in the shell. Do you know how can I display in the browser like the PHP var_dump() function or with javascript console.log() ?
Thanks.

Comment: In fact, I'm using sails.js, based on express, but there is too few help about sails on the net so I said that I was working with express because it's almost the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final solution:

```
module.exports = {
    index: function (req, res) {
        return res.view({
            layout: 'layout',
            title: 'Trip Analyzer',
            routes: req.app.routes
        });
    }
};
```

EJS view in Javascript:

```
console.log(<%- JSON.stringify(routes) %>);
```

Thanks!